# Necessary that $A \cap M = \emptyset $ in $A\cup M \sim M$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have some notes that say $A \cap M = \emptyset $, $M$ infinite, $A$ countable implies $A\cup M \sim M$. Why is the intersection necessarily empty?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, that's a hypothesis, not a conclusion (at least as you state it).

Comment: I believe the question is whether/why it is a necessary hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a necessary hypothesis.  If $B = A \backslash M$, then $B$ is countable, $B \cap M = \emptyset$, and so by the statement in your notes $A \cup M = B \cup M \sim M$.